# Removing html line breaks using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to grab an element's HTML using jQuery and then post it to the server. I successfully grabbed it, but I am not able to remove the white space between the tags and the line breaks that are rendered by default. The HTML code grabbed is shown below:

```
<table><tbody><tr><th></th><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th><th>5</th><th>6</th><th>7</th></tr>
                <tr><th>2nd row</th><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I would like to trim the spaces between the tags only. I've used this regular expression: `str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');`. But that doesn't seem to work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add escape character(backslash - ) character at the end of each line to wrap the string.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you are replacing all consecutive sequences of whitespace with a single space.

This is what you want:

```
str.replace(/>\s+</g, '><');
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help. But, it doesn't work. http://i.stack.imgur.com/VfkXe.png

Comment: the string also contain some line breaks not only spaces.